# Features of the fourier transform for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction

i intend to extract features from time-domain measurement data. I feed the features to machine learning algorithms to detect anomalies.

In the time-domain, i extract mean, RMS, skew and standard deviation. I also want to execute a fourier transform and extract the features from the fourier transform. Intuitively, i would pick the mean frequency and the peak frequency for different frequency bands.

Unfortunately, i cant find any literature on the topic or other people who extracted features from fourier transform (and wavelet, cepstrum, Hilbert, ...) who are smarter than me. can anybody help?

Comment: It seems like you’re losing a ton of information by extracting only those features from the time domain. You’re not treating the data as a time series, and the features you plan to extract from the frequency domain are not such a remedy. It might be more helpful if you describe the machine learning problem you want to solve. // Time series are well-studied in machine learning.  You might get some results by looking into speech recognition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the actual spectrum as your features. E.g. only select the lowest 10,20,30 frequencies. This approach has been used for e.g. [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8898585)